# Derivative of the inverse of a parametric function with respect to the parameter

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given a function

$y = f(x)$

its inverse with respect to the argument *x* is

$x = F(y) = f^{-1}(y)$

Now, suppose that function has a parameter **p**

$y = f(x;p)$

whose inverse is

$x = F(y;p) = f^{-1}(y;p)$

How do I compute the parametric derivative of the inverse function

$\partial{F}(y;p)/\partial{p}$

using the easily computable parametric derivative of the original function

$\partial{f}(x;p)/\partial{p}$

where **p** is actually a vector of parameters. This does not fit the mold of the inverse function theorem as usually presented. It seems too simple to just reciprocate each of the partial derivatives. Could it be something like

$\frac{\partial{F(y;p)}}{\partial{p}}=
-\frac{\partial{f(x;p)}}{\partial{p}} /
\frac{\partial{f(x;p)}}{\partial{x}}
$

?

@Narasimham suggested that I start with a simple problem, then generalize. A simplified version of the problem is

$y = x + k x^3$

with parametric derivative

$d y / d k = x^3$

This is a cubic equation, so luckily there is an analytic inverse -- actually three three of them, but we are only interested in the positive real one.

$x = \frac{2 \sqrt[3]{3} k-\sqrt[3]{2} \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)}-9 k^2 y\right)^{2/3}}{6^{2/3} k
   \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)}-9 k^2 y}}$

Its parametric derivative is

$dx / dk = \frac{-36\ 3^{5/6} k^3 y^2+9 \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt{3} k^2 y^2 \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)}-9 k^2 y\right)^{2/3}+2
   \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt{3} k \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)}-9 k^2 y\right)^{2/3}+12 \sqrt[3]{3} k y \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k
   y^2+4\right)}-3 \sqrt[3]{2} y \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)} \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)}-9 k^2
   y\right)^{2/3}-4\ 3^{5/6} k^2}{6^{2/3} \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)} \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{k^3 \left(27 k y^2+4\right)}-9 k^2
   y\right)^{4/3}}$

But this gives me no insight. Substituting
$y \to x + k x^3$
doesn't simplify things nor provide any insight into extending this to a nonic polynomial. It seems like I could evaluate this expression from the $dy/dk$ derivative.

Comment: Start with a simple case like $ x= 2t, y=t^2$ Observe what happens to the reciprocal of derivative through the parameter, and then generalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following relations
\begin{align}
y &= f(x; p), \tag{1}\\
x &= f^{-1}(y; p). \tag{2}
\end{align}
By taking derivative of (1) with respect to $p$ and by noting (2), we have
$$0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}$$
and hence
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial f^{-1}(y; p)}{\partial p} = - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}. \tag{3}$$

Let us see three examples.

*Example 1*: $y = x + p^2$, its inverse $x = y - p^2$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} = -2p$,
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} = 2p$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1$, (3) is valid.

*Example 2*: $y = x^p$ ($p > 0$, $x > 0$), its inverse $x = y^{1/p}$, 
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} = y^{1/p}\cdot \frac{-1}{p^2}\ln y$,
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} = x^p \ln x$,
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = px^{p-1}$, 
$$- \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}
= - x^p \ln x \cdot \frac{1}{px^{p-1}} = - y \cdot \frac{1}{p}\ln y \cdot \frac{1}{p y^{(p-1)/p}}
= - y^{1/p}\cdot \frac{-1}{p^2}\ln y,$$
(3) is valid.

*Example 3*: $y = x^2 + x(p^2 + p)$ ($p > 0$, $x > 0$), its inverse
$x = - \frac{1}{2}p^2 - \frac{1}{2}p + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{p^4 + 2p^3 + p^2 + 4y}$, $\cdots$, (3) is valid.

Comment: Thank you, River Li.You have the result I was looking for.  I have verified the result numerically, but in the process had to overcome some of my erroneous Jacobian algebra and develop some reliable numerical differentiation.

Comment: @KenTurkowski  You are welcome.